# Is $L^{1}(0,1)\longrightarrow\widetilde{L^{\infty}(0,1)}$, given by $g\longmapsto(f\longmapsto\int_{0}^{1}f(t)g(t)dt)$, a *surjection*?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Is $L^{1}(0,1)\longrightarrow\widetilde{L^{\infty}(0,1)}$, given by $g\longmapsto(f\longmapsto\int_{0}^{1}f(t)g(t)dt)$, a surjection?

My instinct is "no", but I have no idea how to prove it. I guess one has to take a nowhere continuous measurable function $G$ and and then show that $f\mapsto\int_{0}^{1}f(t)G(t)$ is not contained in the image, but I am not sure.

Can anyone give me a nice counterexample?

Comment: Please explain your notation. What is $\widetilde{L^\infty(0,1)}$?

Comment: The dual space.

Comment: The linear dual space? Or another type? Your function is not linear in $f$, so this needs a bit more clarification. Could you add to the OP the formal definition?

Comment: @Jose27: Fixed it.

Comment: Answer: No. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_space

Comment: Is there an easy example of a map $\phi\in Hom(L^{\infty},(0,1))$ that is not in the image of this map?

Comment: You can extend $\phi(f)= \lim_{t\to0^+}f(t)$, from $C[0,1]$ to the whole $L^\infty$ by the Hahn-Banach theorem. It's a fun exercise to show that this (continuous) extension can't be represented by integration against an $L^1$ function.